# Display the locale in a JSTL

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jstl, locale

In a jstl page i want to display the current locale being used to render the page. The page locale is working just fine. When i switch the locale (?lang=nl) the nl resource bundle is used. When is switch back to english (?lang=en) the en resouce bundle is used.

Now i try to display the locale using

```
<c:out value="${ PageContext.request.locale.language }"/>
```

But this just displays the literal string `${ PageContext.request.locale.language }`

I have tried a lot of samples like. With and without the spaces.

```
${ pageContext.request.locale.language }
${ pageContext.locale }
${ pageContext.getLocale }
${ requestContext.locale.language }
${ request.locale.language }
```

I'm using the spring-mvc with the following configuration

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang"/>
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en"/>
</bean>
```

The code for reproducing this problem can be found on https://github.com/abroer/jsltSpringLocaleProblem

Could anyone help me out on this one. Thanks for taking the effort. I really appriciate it.

Comment: Get rid of the spaces. `"${PageContext.request.locale.language}"`

Comment: @EJP, i also tried all the samples without spaces. Same effect. Updated the question.

Comment: Added a link with a sample maven project to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I tried with your example from github and it seems to work for me with the expression -

```
<c:out value="${pageContext.request.locale.language}"/>
```

The only thing I had to change was the webapp namespace and schema to 2.5 as opposed to version 2.3 in your web.xml file as I'm using jdk 7 with tomcat 7.

Comment: Thanks @Ivey setting the webapp to 2.5 solved the problem. I have updated the github repository to reflect your solution. Key to the problem was that the $ statements did not evaluate.